# Como definir as configurações de um plugin junto às configurações do Next.js?

Tags: javascript, react, next.js

Tenho um projeto que usa uma dependência chamada `@uiw/react-md-editor` e, para que funcione com Next.js, preciso criar o arquivo `next.config.js` e colocar este código:

```js
// next.config.js
const removeImports = require('next-remove-imports')();

module.exports = removeImports({});
```

E isto funciona.

Mas quando preciso definir as configurações do próprio Next.js nesse arquivo (nesse caso para permitir acesso de imagens de outros domínios), tenho que fazer isto:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: [
      'localhost',
      '10.0.0.164',
      'exemplo.com',
      'exemplo.com.br'
    ]
  }
};
```

Aí que começa o problema. Não consigo usar os dois códigos no mesmo arquivo, o que era para ser algo simples).

Já tentei declarar dois `module.exports` separados, já tentei exportar um objeto com os dois, um array, e tudo que conheço. Mas só "funciona" se tiver um ou o outro. Mas se tiver só um então vou ter que remover a lógica do outro do app e quero usar os dois recursos. Já pesquisei e encontrei alguns exemplos de como fazer isso, mas todos estão desatualizados.

> Observe que esse exemplo não acontece apenas com essa biblioteca. Sempre que preciso exportar duas configurações (de um *plugin* e do Next.js, por exemplo), dá erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você realmente não pode ter dois `module.exports`, já que cada módulo do CommonJS pode ter apenas um *entry point* (denotado pelo `exports`).

---

Geralmente a configuração de *plugins* do Next.js aceita o aninhamento das funções e configurações. Por exemplo:

```
//                                        Configurações do plugin
//                                                   ↓↓
const removeImports = require('next-remove-imports')({});

//                  Configurações do Next.js
//                             ↓
module.exports = removeImports({
  images: {
    domains: [
      'localhost',
      '10.0.0.164',
      'exemplo.com',
      'exemplo.com.br'
    ]
  }
});
```

Repare que o módulo `next-remove-imports` exporta uma função que aceita, como único argumento, um objeto com as configurações para o *plugin*. Essa função retorna uma outra função que, por sua vez, aceita as configurações do Next.js.

Esse comportamento pode ser feito para vários *plugins*, de modo que as configurações vão sendo "aninhadas" para cada um deles.

Veja que isso é demonstrado no [*readme*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-remove-imports) do *plugin* em questão.

Comment: Testado e aprovado! Muito obrigado... só não entendi porque outros exemplos que olhei, até dependencias externas mandavam eu instalar rsrsrs.